# Can I npm run watch with php artisan serve?

Tags: laravel, npm-scripts

Can I run npm watch and php artisan serve within the same npm script? I've tried the following: npm watch and browser-sync both work, but php artisan serve is not getting triggered.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch && npm run artisan",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "artisan": "php artisan serve"
},
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.browserSync('http://localhost:8000/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to run multiple processes. In your case it might be possible to add something like this in your `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "serve": "php artisan serve --host=domain.test --port=8080 & npm run watch"
    },
    ...
}
```

But I would rather use apache or nginx on you local machine to run your php application. Laravel has two beautiful packages for developing php applications on you local machine:

**Valet**
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet

**Homestead**
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead

When you use one of these, you don't need to run `php artisan serve` any more.

This way you also don't have to mix up your artisan and npm scripts/commands. When running both commands in the same window, it will output both your php server and webpack output. That just hurts ;)
package.json contains javascript configurations, and artisan is php based. It feels a little weird to place php commands in your package.json.

Comment: For laravel this won't work because serve never ends until you end it. And running in parallel isn't possible via -p in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is you're using and controlling the cli via Windows cmd, rather than through an IDE, you can do the following:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "run": "start npm run serve && start npm run watch"
    "serve": "php artisan serve"
},
```

...or you can have one run in the IDE and the other run in windows cmd:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "run": "npm run serve && start npm run watch"
    "serve": "php artisan serve"
},
```